# QSerialPort in while Loop?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtcore, qtserialport

I have a function that sends data over RS-232 to Hyperterminal. The function works properly out of the while loop, however, in the while loop, it sends only at the first time after that it doesn't send anything.

```
    qDebug() << MESSAGE;
    int choice;
    std::cin >> choice;

    while( choice != 3 )
    {
        switch (choice)
        {
            case 1:
                // Ready to send data 
                port->write("QSerial Port!\r\n");
                break;
            case 2:
                qDebug() << "Todo...";
                break;
            case 3:
                break;
            default:
                qDebug() << "Invalid Choice ...";
        }
        qDebug() << MESSAGE;
        std::cin >> choice;
    }
```

Edit:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <iostream>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QSerialPort>

const char MESSAGE[] = "\n----- New Menu ----"
                       "\n1- Send Data     \n"
                       "2- Receive Data    \n"
                       "3- Quit:           \n";


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication  app(argc, argv);

    QSerialPort *port = new QSerialPort;
    port->setPortName("COM4");


    // Check the validity of the port
    if ( !port->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite) )
    {
        qDebug() << "\nError: " << port->portName() << " port can't be opened ...";
        return -1;
    }else{
        qDebug() << '\n' << port->portName() << " port has been opened successfully ...";
        port->setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud9600);
        port->setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);
        port->setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
        port->setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
        port->setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);
        qDebug() << port->portName() << " port has been configured correctly ...";
    }

    qDebug() << MESSAGE;
    int choice;
    std::cin >> choice;

    while( choice != 3 )
    {
        switch (choice)
        {
            case 1:
            {
                // Ready to send data 
                if ( port->write("QSerial Port!\r\n", qstrlen("QSerial Port!\r\n")) == -1)
                {
                    qDebug() << port->errorString();
                }
                //port->bytesWritten(strlen("QSerial Port!\r\n"));
                port->waitForBytesWritten(-1);
                //qDebug() << port->errorString();
            }
                break;
            case 2:
                qDebug() << "Todo...";
                break;
            case 3:
                break;
            default:
                qDebug() << "Invalid Choice ...";
        }
        qDebug() << MESSAGE;
        std::cin >> choice;
    }

    qDebug() << "\n Goodbye ....";
    port->close();
    delete port;
    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Please show the output of `port->errorString()`. Also, please show how you configure the qtserialport object, how you open it. You are using QtSerialPort 5.2.1, right?

Comment: `if ( port->write("QSerial Port!\r\n", qstrlen("QSerial Port!\r\n")) == -1)
{
  qDebug() << port->errorString();
}`

Comment: This is my function to check the error but I got nothing. I don't think so there is an error, however, I guess what you said is right that is the problem with the waiting time to send the next data.

Comment: Which operating system is this? Is it 32 or 64 bit? Is it QtSerialPort 5.2.1 or with Qt 4? Usb serial or native?

Comment: 64 bit Windows, QtSerialPort 5.2.1. Virtual Serial Port driver

Comment: Windows 7 or something else? Why don't you check against data loss, just -1? Also, you do not seem to check the return value of the waitForBytesWritten method. Does that method succeed? Also, when you print the errorString(), it is better to put some prefix in there not to get lost in the output. Can you reproduce this issue without "cin" and input, just by running the write in a loop iterating thrice? Furthermore, it is better to check all the settings after the open IMHO. Do any of those fail? By the way, it is C++ and semi-raii. You do not need to close the port explicitly here.

Comment: It is Windows 7. I think the problem was from the buffer. Every time, I send data I need to clear the buffer, so I did that by using `port->clear()`. The only problem now is that every time I send `Q`, I receive `QQ`. Why do I receive the data doubled?

Comment: Does it also happen with real serial port, like native sub-9 or usb-serial like PL2303?

Comment: I'm using Hyperterminal to carry out this experiment and Virtual Serial Port Driver to make the connection.

Comment: I'm not really sure about the size of the buffer. What I'm thinking is that the buffer will be send once it is filled out, but my understanding of serial port is that the data is send byte by byte.

Comment: Can you try with a native or usb serial port for a quick test to see if this behavior is Vierual Serial Port Driver specific?

Comment: Unfortunately  I don't have hardware right now. Do you suggest any other software for whether Hyperterminal or Virtual Serial Port Driver? Another question do you know how to  get the size of outcome buffer?

Comment: I've used another software namely "putty". The result is same, so now I'm sure the problem is not from Hyperterminal. I suspect Qt. Any suggestions?

Comment: The problem has been solved. The problem was HHD Virtual Serial Port Driver. It echos any data that is send and there is no even setting for this software.

Comment: Downvote? Why? I've explained the problem clearly and I showed my effort to get to work. It is unfair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has the following flaws:

1) You do not handle the errors.

2) You do not check the return value of the write operation.

3) You do not seem to wait programatically before writing again. This is not correct. Either use the sync waitForBytesWritten or the async bytesWritten signal to give green light for the next write.

The most critical is probably the last point. It would result "random" behavior how the data is sent out. In this special case, it would probably be sent sequentially as waiting for the input probably takes you longer time, but it is still not stable and robust code to write.

Comment: I think you are right about the last point you did mention. if I use `port->waitForBytesWritten(-1);`, it did exactly what I'm looking for however it behaves strangely. For example, the first time it sends `QSerial Port!\r\n` once. The second time I send it, the message is doubled. The third time the message is  tripled and so on.

Comment: @CroCo: show the whole code that reproduces the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I can't completely agree with point (3).
There is nothing which says you can't do a second write, whilst the first is still outstanding. In principle the data should just be added to the transmit queue.
It would be like saying "You can't write again to this file until the previous data has been written to disk".
I had a similar problem with qtserial where I was doing:

```
while (..)
{
    <send data>
    <receive data>
}
```

Turns out you HAVE to do a qApp->processEvents() before you can receive anything
or before you can write new data. 
I was expecting the same behavior as for reading/writing a file. 
To me qtserial is NOT behaving as you would expect a device to.

Comment: you are right. After using `qApp->processEvent()` it behaves as I expected. It is strange that in the documentation there is nothing about using qApp->processEvents() for QSerialPort Class.

Comment: @CroCo: fwiw, I am one of the QtSerialPort contributors along with Sergey, and this answer does not feel right from what I can say. Processing events explicitly should not be necessary. Even if it seems to work, it is not the correct way. I still stick by what I said would be true. That is how the library was designed. You can write continously in general, but in this case, I thought you would process the messages in chunks on the other side?

Comment: @LaszloPapp, thank you so much again for your advice. Could you please provide me with simple example so that I can test it. Theoretically what Gert said is correct but I'm still confused about QSerialPort Class. I've seen many ppl complain about while loop in Qt in general. There is something hidden at least for beginners about this issue.