# QtSerialPort: duplicate reads on Windows 7

Tags: c++, qt, serial-port, qtserialport

My application is communicating with an embedded system via serial port (usb serial).

I'm developing with Qt 4.8 and QtSerialPort from gitorious (https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtserialport/) and I'm also testing in a VM with Windows 7 and Qt 5.2.1

It works fine under Linux, but I get double, triple quadruple reads of the same message.
I can verify that these messages are only sent once, communicating via puTTY.

So the question is, is it an issue with QtSerialPort, the VM (although it works with putty?), the serial driver... etc.

Is this a known issue? (I couldn't find anything, though)
Any ideas how to get to the bottom of this?

this is how I read:

EDIT: moar code:

```
ModuleCommunicator::ModuleCommunicator(const QString &device, SBStateModel &state_model)
: upstate(UpdateDone), model(state_model)
{
port = new QSerialPort(device);

if (!port->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite /*| QIODevice::Truncate*/)) {
    qDebug() << "Failed to open - Portname: " << port->portName() << endl;
    qDebug() << "Error: " << port->errorString() << endl;

    return;
}

port->setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud115200, QSerialPort::AllDirections);
port->setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
port->setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);
port->setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
port->setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);

msgBuffer = new QStringList();

log_init = false;

connect(port, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(onReadyRead()));
connect(port, SIGNAL(error(QSerialPort::SerialPortError)), this, SLOT(onError(QSerialPort::SerialPortError)));
connect(port, SIGNAL(aboutToClose()), this, SLOT(devClosing()));

/* Timer for log level */
conTimer = new QTimer(this);
connect(conTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(timerFired()));
}

ModuleCommunicator::~ModuleCommunicator()
{
  if (port->isOpen())
      port->close();
  delete msgBuffer;
  delete port;
}

...
void ModuleCommunicator::onReadyRead()
{
if (port->bytesAvailable()) {
    QString msg = QString(port->readAll());
    msgBuffer->append(msg);

    if (msg.endsWith("\n")) {
        msg = msgBuffer->join("").trimmed();
        msgBuffer->clear();
        msgBuffer->append(msg.split("\r\n"));
    } else {
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < msgBuffer->size(); i++) {
        msg = msgBuffer->at(i);

        qDebug() << "MSG: " << msg << endl;

        if (isResponse(msg)) {
            handleMsg(msg);
        }
    }

    msgBuffer->clear();
}
}
```

EDIT: Interesting. Uncommenting a "flush()" makes things work. With the flush I see multiplied messages. But on the receiving end? Is it possible, that messages are SENT multiple times because of "flush()"?

```
void ModuleCommunicator::handleMsg(const QString &msg)
{
// Parse msg
QSharedPointer<USBResponse> resp = QSharedPointer<USBResponse>(parse_message(msg));

if (!resp->is_valid()) {
    // LOG
    return; // Invalid response
}

// omitted 

/* Find completion handler for response
  Match to first command in Queue with same command & address,
  or same command and wildcard adress */
// Omitted

// Sending next msg in queue if there is one
if (!sendQueue.isEmpty()) {
    QueuedCommand qc = sendQueue.takeFirst();
    QString nxtcmd = qc.cmdstr;
    completionHandlerQueue.append(qc.ch);
    qDebug() << "handleMsg: Sending next msg: " << qc.cmdstr;
    if (port->write(nxtcmd.toLatin1()) == -1) {
        qDebug() << "handleMsg: write failed!";
    }
    // !!! Removing the following line makes things work?!
    port->flush();
}

return;
```

}

Comment: maybe connect() is run several times? The slot is called for each connect() that was run

Comment: Someone [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22443020/qserialport-in-while-loop) experienced data duplication, but I am not sure if it is related. Can you provide a full test case with the main function included? Do the examples work as you expect them, too?

Comment: @lizusek: Well, it's a consuming read, so it shouldn't read the same stuff twice. But I have checked now, that connect() is only called once. Also, it doesn't happen on Linux, only on Windows - but same code.

Comment: @LaszloPapp: I've tested the Terminal example and that works fine, so the bug is somewhere in my application. The code is too large, I'll have to see if I can extract smthg. But for now I'm checking the points you made in the other post. I'm not handling the error signal or the write signal (although writes work fine. I write and flush. But usually I write only after receiving confirmation)

Comment: @BenjaminMaurer: I would suggest to start testing with something simpler than the terminal example, e.g. the async command line reader and writer.

Comment: @LaszloPapp: Both the Terminal and the async-read examples work perfectly fine... 
I don't get write errors or error signals while active, only when closing I get Error 13. But that's not related.

Comment: OK, that is a good sign! Can you share the whole code including the connect statement, too?

Comment: Here it is, hope it's not too much code.

Comment: So in the end I tried to change some settings in the drivers configuration (We're using STM32 Virtual COM Port Driver(STSW-STM32102)). Actually, I only changed the Baudrate setting and nothing else. Unexpectedly, it worked afterwards! I'm confused though, I though QtSerialPort should be able to change the baud rate. Maybe the driver is defective. I will investigate this further on Monday when back at the office.

Comment: OK I was wrong. The driver had nothing to do with it. I just had uncommented a bunch of code. The line "port->flush()" makes or breaks things. Any idea why that might happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issues was caused by calling the "flush" method.
Removing flush calls after writing to the serial port fixes the problem.

It seems like there are known issues with the "flush" method (although a hint in the documentation would be nice, until it is fixed). Here is the bug report I found:

https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-36726

Quote:

> Yes, a flush() method has bugs yet. Please do not use a flush().